# When long expression is written in multi-line, the symbol should put at end of line or first of next line?

Tags: expression

When the expression is too long and cannot fit into the display area or for source code neatness, we will write the long expression in multi-line. I tried to check related programming rules but I cannot find some related about the **symbol** should put at **end of line** or first of next line.

For example long IF expression in C# code,

```
if (!double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue)||
        !double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue)||
        !double.TryParse(text10Hours.Text, out outputValue)){ }
```

OR

```
if (!double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue)
        ||!double.TryParse(text4Hours.Text, out outputValue)
        ||!double.TryParse(text10Hours.Text, out outputValue)){ }
```

The parallel symbol || can be put at end of line or first of next line, **any rules** states that we must follow the first or second one? What are the **advantages** to do like that?

Another example is

```
        answer = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text) +
                amount8Hours * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) - 
                    break45 * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) +
                amount10Hours * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text) -
                    break45 * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text);
```

OR

```
            answer = amount4Hours * double.Parse(text4Hours.Text) 
                    +amount8Hours * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text)  
                        -break45 * double.Parse(text8Hours.Text) 
                    +amount10Hours * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text) 
                        -break45 * double.Parse(text10Hours.Text);
```

I know we should try to avoid have long expression but if consider the reason of display area of the text editor is small or other issues, then this question will still pop out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe any answers for this question will be opinion based, but I also believe that most people would prefer the first approach. Imagine something like:

```
if (expression1 &&
        expression243787 &&
        expression3 &&
        expression938533485934 &&
        expression7247)
```

Now imagine that you catch a bug on your code and realize that the logic error is in this expression, where all && operators should be || instead. It might just be an opinion, but I do think that it would be much easier to fix that if the code was like this:

```
if (expression1
        && expression243787
        && expression3
        && expression938533485934
        && expression7247)
```

This is just an example that illustrates why I think this practice makes code refactoring easier, besides other benefits, like readability.

Comment: If we always like to put comment at same line,I agree that put symbol at front better to avoid misunderstanding in this case

Answer (score 0):

Putting the symbol at the start of the next line will show the symbol more easily.  If at the end of the previous line, the symbol sequence is harder to follow.

Comment: If the symbols is OR symbol and same case with my example which followed by ! symbol, I prefer put OR symbol at end of line because || is similar to !